# Which version of jQuery / jQuery UI to use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery framework and jQuery UI components are very popular, there are millions of users. The problem to me are the breaking changes that jQuery and jQuery UI team had done, example i developed a system with jQuery UI 1.8 version now I upgrade to jQuery 1.9 and many things doesn't work anymore, I have read the reasons of the jQuery UI team for these changes, but to me all those reasons are simply unaceptable because they hadn't thought in the millions of users that their code will not work anymore and the books published with jQuery 1.7 / jQuery UI 1.8, those books doesn't work anymore, for example jQuery in Action 2d edition.

So my question is: Based in your experience does it worth to upgrade to jQuery 1.9 / jQuery UI 1.9 ?
The versions that I see very used are jQuery 1.7 and jQuery UI 1.8

In short: Based on your experience which version of jQuery / jQuery UI do you recommend to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't worth the change if you don't require the new features or fixes. The benefit required may outweigh the work/problems you are going to encounter making the changes needed to adapt your application to the new API.

In my project I found version 1.9 improvements interesting but it wasn't worth the time needed to adapt our code.

My advice is that if you are on a very strict time-scale don't mess with the bleeding edge versions, it will cause a lot of stress.

In our case, we started using jQuery 1.8.0 and later updated to 1.8.1 because some bugfixes were required, it needed some testing time, just over one day. Moving to 1.9.1 resulted in a rollback, we would have needed extensive rewriting of code already working and to repeat all the testing.

We upgraded to jQuery UI 1.8.18, 1.8.22 and 1.8.23 with no more pain than adjusting the themeroller.

Comment: But do you think that in a near future it will worth the effort?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure because jQuery 1.9 is a breaking change even using the adaptation layer they published too. But in my case we have a time schedule that we can't change.

Comment: To me this is the best of the answers, what I miss is that you didn't  point the versions to use

Comment: I Hope you find it complete enough, and thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

> but to me all those reasons are simply unaceptable because they hadn't thought in the millions of users that their code will not work anymore

The jQuery team did think of it. There's a jQuery migrate plugin you can [download](http://jquery.com/download/) and read about it on their github page at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

As for which version to use. Use the latest version. Upgrade your plugins when you can, don't be lazy. Most worthwhile plugins out there that are not working for you in 1.9 have probably been updated so all you need to do is go and get the updated plugins.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it, but I see only for migrate jQuery framework not to migrate jQuery UI UI

Comment: I'm not lazy I'm a developer in charge of many systems, can't say to my boss: hey I'm taking a week migrating every system to jQuery UI if doesn't worth it

Comment: Not to mention all the book authors that probably are angry with those  changes in jQuery / jQuery UI that leave their books outdated in a second

Comment: If you're a computer science book author and you're angry about _that_, then you've entered the wrong industry. Write about history instead.

Comment: @Mike Campbell An author can't write or rewrite books at will of the 'iluminated' and  arbitrary design decisions. It's responsability of the API designers to THINK well about their product before launch it, I disagree with APIs that in 1.8 to 1.9 everything fells down

Comment: If you're using books printed on paper to describe constantly evolving state-of-the-art technologies then you only have yourself to blame. You can't always make non-breaking updates, and you shouldn't. If you want the old version, stay in the past.

Answer (score 3):

***Never upgrade for upgrade's sake.***  If you don't have a reason to upgrade, then don't upgrade.  That's the most important rule of IT in a corporate setting.  If something works, don't introduce new variables into the mix that can break things.  Don't upgrade until you need to do something that's impossible (or very painful) with the current version.

Also, **NEVER** directly link to jquery-latest.  Link to whatever version your application needs, linking to jquery-latest makes you vulnerable to breaking changes when things you need are changed or removed.

Comment: I agree with not linking to jquery-latest, but the idea of definitely NOT upgrading _unless you need to_, I don't agree with that. You certainly don't have to upgrade, but it's a good idea to try and keep your libraries up-to-date when you can, as that moment that you do find you need the latest version to do something, you won't have to upgrade from version 0.0.1 to version 9.0.0, maybe just 8.9.9->9.0.0, which will be significantly easier. Anyway, if you have a test suite you'll know you're not introducing bugs anyway.

Answer (score -2):

use stable latest version such like jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 :)

Comment: Please justify why I should use those versions

Comment: Additional detail would improve this answer.